# arcpy.MakeTableView returns empty result object on second iteration of loop

Tags: arcpy, python, raster, mosaic

I've encountered a very strange problem involving a geoprocessing tool in ArcPy that I have spent too much time trying to solve on my own.

Specifically, I have a process that iterates through a list of folders with images, adds those images to an existing mosaic dataset (in a file geodatabase), and then updates metadata for the added raster within the mosaic dataset attribute table, based on metadata stored in an associated JSON file.

Earlier in this workflow, a previously-run tool generates folder names (based on an image name obtained from the JSON file), and if the process finds a folder name will be duplicated, the folder name is appended with a numerical suffix (i.e. '..\20200509_135639_**1010**', '..\20200509_135639_**1010_01**' ).

All raster files are added to the mosaic dataset w/o issue. However, when I try to update the metadata associated with each rasterin the mosaic dataset attribute table (again based on values stored in an associated JSON file) the problem occurs.

I attempt to create a temporary Table View for one raster record, based on a query in which I select the newly-added raster based on the image's "product name" in the mosaic dataset attribute table. This works for the first image in a list, but NOT for the subsequent images which have the appended suffix (i.e. "_01", "_02", etc.)

No matter how I change the values associated with the suffix ("01" or "_1", etc.) the arcpy.MakeTableView_management always return an empty result object on all subsequent "suffixed" raster names.

Here is the offending code snippet that returns an empty result on the "suffixed" raster names:

*Example variable values*

- `srcMosaic = '\\\\SERVER_NAME\\DIR\\SUBDIR\\SourceMosaics.gdb\\PlanetScope'`
- `whereClause = "ProductName = '20200509_135639_1020_01'`

```
def updateMetadataFromUser(srcMosaic, whereClause, collectionName, collectionType, imageType, source, sensor, year, startDate, endDate, resolution_meters, loadedBy):
    metaTable = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table=srcMosaic, out_view="tmpMetaTable", where_clause=whereClause)

    #Populate the table with attributes collected from getRasterCollectionInfo and getRasterInfo
    metaCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(metaTable)[0]
```

The `metaCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(metaTable)[0]` returns an error when the metaTable result object is empty.

Here's an example of the image names:

- '20200509_135639_1020' (*metadata fields updated successfully in mosaic attribute table*)
- '20200509_135639_1020_01' (*returns empty result from MakeTableView*)

Another bizarre aspect to this is that if I just run the tool using only the image with the suffix (for instance 20200509_135639_**1020_01**), then arcpy.MakeTableView find the record and returns a result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you delete the TableView anywhere in your code `arcpy.Delete_management("tempMetaTable")` before you try to create it again?

Comment: Yes, I delete TableView at the end of each function call.  Although I just realized I'm use `del` and not `arcpy.Delete_managment()`

Answer (score 1):

So Bjorn was right (in the comments).  Turns out the issue had nothing to do with the suffix.  I was deleting the table view using `del`, instead of `arcpy.DeleteManagement()`.  That solved it!